# Multiple file-extensions searchPattern for System.IO.Directory.GetFiles

Tags: c#, .net, system.io.directory

What is the syntax for setting **multiple file-extensions** as `searchPattern` on `Directory.GetFiles()`? For example filtering out files with *.aspx* and *.ascx* extensions.

```
// TODO: Set the string 'searchPattern' to only get files with
// the extension '.aspx' and '.ascx'.
var filteredFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, searchPattern);
```

**Update**: **LINQ is not an option**, it has to be a `searchPattern` passed into `GetFiles`, as specified in the question.

Comment: I don't think there is any. Either list all files and then filter manually or perform a union on multiple searcher. But I'm pretty sure I have seen this exact question on SO before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527203/getfiles-with-multiple-extentions

Comment: Previously asked and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters

Comment: Why would LINQ ever not be an option? It's a very common library in .NET and should be used when necessary.

Comment: @MarkEntingh Using LINQ requires the code to iterate all files on disk and filter it "client-side". While providing a string (or similar) to something on OS API-level might have the chance to use some kind of smart cache in filesystem or OS, to improve performance.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I believe there is no "out of the box" solution, that's a limitation of the Directory.GetFiles method.

It's fairly easy to write your own method though, here is an [example](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-FAQ/Multiple-Filters-Directory.GetFiles-Method.aspx).

The code could be:

> ```
> /// <summary>
> /// Returns file names from given folder that comply to given filters
> /// </summary>
> /// <param name="SourceFolder">Folder with files to retrieve</param>
> /// <param name="Filter">Multiple file filters separated by | character</param>
> /// <param name="searchOption">File.IO.SearchOption, 
> /// could be AllDirectories or TopDirectoryOnly</param>
> /// <returns>Array of FileInfo objects that presents collection of file names that 
> /// meet given filter</returns>
> public string[] getFiles(string SourceFolder, string Filter, 
>  System.IO.SearchOption searchOption)
> {
>  // ArrayList will hold all file names
> ArrayList alFiles = new ArrayList();
>
>  // Create an array of filter string
>  string[] MultipleFilters = Filter.Split('|');
>
>  // for each filter find mathing file names
>  foreach (string FileFilter in MultipleFilters)
>  {
>   // add found file names to array list
>   alFiles.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(SourceFolder, FileFilter, searchOption));
>  }
>
>  // returns string array of relevant file names
>  return (string[])alFiles.ToArray(typeof(string));
> }
> ```

Comment: This is a very insufficient way of doing it, since you will loop entire directory for each filter. Instead you should check for each file if it has the filter then add to do the list. You can use the answer explained in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754118/how-to-filter-directory-enumeratefiles-with-multiple-criteria

Answer (score 208):

```
var filteredFiles = Directory
    .GetFiles(path, "*.*")
    .Where(file => file.ToLower().EndsWith("aspx") || file.ToLower().EndsWith("ascx"))
    .ToList();
```

**Edit 2014-07-23**

You can do this in .NET 4.5 for a faster enumeration:

```
var filteredFiles = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(path) //<--- .NET 4.5
    .Where(file => file.ToLower().EndsWith("aspx") || file.ToLower().EndsWith("ascx"))
    .ToList();
```

[Directory.EnumerateFiles in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383458(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: +1 beat me to it :) does the double pipe need another enclosing bracket though?

Comment: Are you sure that's correct? The GetFiles method returns an array of FileInfo objects, not strings. How can you apply the EndsWith method?

Comment: @Mario Vernari: `GetFiles` returns `string[]`.

Comment: @Jgauffin: You are right! Sorry, I mismatched with DirectoryInfo. I have corrected my post as well.

Comment: You must remove the * from the EndsWith() argument, it doesn't do wildcard matches.

Comment: if compare extensions of file it will return exact match like '.Where(file => new FileInfo(file).Extension.Equals(".aspx") || new FileInfo(file).Extension.Equals(".ascx"))'

Comment: @Damith Indeed but I think it will be heavier

Comment: Don't forget the new .NET4 `Directory.EnumerateFiles` for a performance boost... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669617/what-is-the-difference-between-directory-enumeratefiles-vs-directory-getfiles

Comment: And you can always use `file.EndsWith("...", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);` rather than `ToLower`

Comment: Last comment -- I think combining multiple searches is much faster:  `"*.ext1;*.ext2".Split(';').SelectMany(g => Directory.GetFiles(path, g)).ToList()`

Comment: @drzaus: Why don't you put that in a new answer. I would upvote it.

Comment: @jgauffin done, thank you.  i <3 points.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19933502/1037948

Comment: Path.GetExtension() is better for getting file extension, at least you shoud add dot before extension type like ".aspx"

Answer (score 50):

I like this method, because it is readable and avoids multiple iterations of the directory:

```
var allowedExtensions = new [] {".doc", ".docx", ".pdf", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".xls", ".xslx"}; 
var files = Directory
    .GetFiles(folder)
    .Where(file => allowedExtensions.Any(file.ToLower().EndsWith))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I like this a lot better because I don't have to parse my extension array and add it to regex or other manual work. Thanks!

Comment: @Jodrell, or simply a `HashSet<string>`

Comment: HashSet<string> instead of an array for the extension makes no sense here, as the number of extensions is limited and the array gets iterated for each file, until EndsWith() gets true. If the method needs to be tuned for performance for a very large number of extensions, a Hashset could be used. In order to take effect, the extension of each file would then need to be matched explicitly (split, then match) instead of the EndsWith()-method. This will harm readibility and will be of no significant use in most if not all real life use cases. I therefor rolled back the community edit.

Answer (score 31):

GetFiles can only match a single pattern, but you can use Linq to invoke GetFiles with multiple patterns:

```
FileInfo[] fi = new string[]{"*.txt","*.doc"}
    .SelectMany(i => di.GetFiles(i, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    .ToArray();
```

See comments section here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/NET_DirectoryInfo.aspx

Comment: They'll collide if the patterns overlap.  E.g., `new string[]{"*.txt","filename.*"}`.  However, the call to `Distinct` doesn't actually resolve this problem, since FileInfo objects compare using reference equality, not semantic equality.  It could be fixed by either removing the `Distinct` or passing it an `IEqualityComparer<FileInfo>`.  Edited to do the former.

Comment: I would think that `SelectMany` will iterate over the same file structure again (and again) so it might be sub-optimal in terms of performance.

Answer (score 16):

```
var filteredFiles = Directory
    .EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*") // .NET4 better than `GetFiles`
    .Where(
        // ignorecase faster than tolower...
        file => file.ToLower().EndsWith("aspx")
        || file.EndsWith("ascx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    .ToList();
```

- Don't forget the new .NET4 `Directory.EnumerateFiles` for a performance boost ([What is the difference between Directory.EnumerateFiles vs Directory.GetFiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5669617/what-is-the-difference-between-directory-enumeratefiles-vs-directory-getfiles))
- "IgnoreCase" should be faster than "ToLower"

Or, it may be faster to split and merge your globs (at least it looks cleaner):

```
"*.ext1;*.ext2".Split(';')
    .SelectMany(g => Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, g))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: and reposting on "original" question with more detail -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters/19961761#19961761

Answer (score 15):

I fear you will have to do somthing like this, I mutated the regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081555/testing-for-endswith-efficiently-with-a-regex).

```
var searchPattern = new Regex(
    @"$(?<=\.(aspx|ascx))", 
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
    .Where(f => searchPattern.IsMatch(f))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: this seems to be a nice approach, the missing part is to have a tested (working) regular expression

Answer (score 12):

The easy-to-remember, lazy and perhaps imperfect solution:

```
Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.dll").Union(Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.exe"))
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use the following:

```
var ext = new string[] { ".ASPX", ".ASCX" };
FileInfo[] collection = (from fi in new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles()
                         where ext.Contains(fi.Extension.ToUpper())
                         select fi)
                         .ToArray();
```

EDIT: corrected due mismatch between Directory and DirectoryInfo

Answer (score 3):

I would try to specify something like

```
var searchPattern = "as?x";
```

it should work.

Comment: Hah! I was afraid that aspx and ascx was too similar and would render a hack-solution like this. I want something general.

Answer (score 3):

A more efficient way of getting files with the extensions ".aspx" and ".ascx"
that avoids querying the file system several times and avoids returning a lot of undesired files, is to pre-filter the files by using an approximate search pattern and to refine the result afterwards:

```
var filteredFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.as?x")
    .Select(f => f.ToLowerInvariant())
    .Where(f => f.EndsWith("px") || f.EndsWith("cx"))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this

```
new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles().Where(Current => Regex.IsMatch(Current.Extension, "\\.(aspx|ascx)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: In Question is: LINQ is not an option, so this answer is not useful

Comment: Many questions here use LINQ, even the highest voted one, so tbh this comment isn't very useful

Answer (score 2):

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the names of files in a specified directories that match the specified patterns using LINQ
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="srcDirs">The directories to seach</param>
    /// <param name="searchPatterns">the list of search patterns</param>
    /// <param name="searchOption"></param>
    /// <returns>The list of files that match the specified pattern</returns>
    public static string[] GetFilesUsingLINQ(string[] srcDirs,
         string[] searchPatterns,
         SearchOption searchOption = SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    {
        var r = from dir in srcDirs
                from searchPattern in searchPatterns
                from f in Directory.GetFiles(dir, searchPattern, searchOption)
                select f;

        return r.ToArray();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    public static bool CheckFiles(string pathA, string pathB)
    {
        string[] extantionFormat = new string[] { ".war", ".pkg" };
        return CheckFiles(pathA, pathB, extantionFormat);
    }
    public static bool CheckFiles(string pathA, string pathB, string[] extantionFormat)
    {
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir1 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathA);
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir2 = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(pathB);
        // Take a snapshot of the file system. list1/2 will contain only WAR or PKG 
        // files
        // fileInfosA will contain all of files under path directories 
        FileInfo[] fileInfosA = dir1.GetFiles("*.*", 
                              System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        // list will contain all of files that have ..extantion[]  
        // Run on all extantion in extantion array and compare them by lower case to 
        // the file item extantion ...
        List<System.IO.FileInfo> list1 = (from extItem in extantionFormat
                                          from fileItem in fileInfosA
                                          where extItem.ToLower().Equals 
                                          (fileItem.Extension.ToLower())
                                          select fileItem).ToList();
        // Take a snapshot of the file system. list1/2 will contain only WAR or  
        // PKG files
        // fileInfosA will contain all of files under path directories 
        FileInfo[] fileInfosB = dir2.GetFiles("*.*", 
                                       System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
        // list will contain all of files that have ..extantion[]  
        // Run on all extantion in extantion array and compare them by lower case to 
        // the file item extantion ...
        List<System.IO.FileInfo> list2 = (from extItem in extantionFormat
                                          from fileItem in fileInfosB
                                          where extItem.ToLower().Equals            
                                          (fileItem.Extension.ToLower())
                                          select fileItem).ToList();
        FileCompare myFileCompare = new FileCompare();
        // This query determines whether the two folders contain 
        // identical file lists, based on the custom file comparer 
        // that is defined in the FileCompare class. 
        return list1.SequenceEqual(list2, myFileCompare);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the EndsWith function, I would choose to use the `Path.GetExtension()` method instead. Here is the full example:

```
var filteredFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles( path )
.Where(
    file => Path.GetExtension(file).Equals( ".aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ||
            Path.GetExtension(file).Equals( ".ascx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) );
```

or:

```
var filteredFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
.Where(
    file => string.Equals( Path.GetExtension(file), ".aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) ||
            string.Equals( Path.GetExtension(file), ".ascx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase ) );
```

(Use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` if you care about performance: [MSDN string comparisons](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx))

Answer (score 1):

look like this demo:

```
void Main()
{
    foreach(var f in GetFilesToProcess("c:\\", new[] {".xml", ".txt"}))
        Debug.WriteLine(f);
}
private static IEnumerable<string> GetFilesToProcess(string path, IEnumerable<string> extensions)
{
   return Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*")
       .Where(f => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower()));
}
```

Comment: You have `Path.GetExtension` which you can use.

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel B, thanks for the suggestion to write my own version of this function. It has the same behavior as Directory.GetFiles, but supports regex filtering.

```
string[] FindFiles(FolderBrowserDialog dialog, string pattern)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);

        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        var files=Directory.GetFiles(dialog.SelectedPath);
        for(int i = 0; i < files.Count(); i++)
        {
            bool found = regex.IsMatch(files[i]);
            if(found)
            {
                files.Add(files[i]);
            }
        }

        return files.ToArray();
    }
```

I found it useful, so I thought I'd share.

Answer (score 1):

c# version of @qfactor77's answer. This is the best way without LINQ .

```
string[] wildcards= {"*.mp4", "*.jpg"};
ReadOnlyCollection<string> filePathCollection = FileSystem.GetFiles(dirPath, Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, wildcards);
string[] filePath=new string[filePathCollection.Count];
filePathCollection.CopyTo(filePath,0);
```

now return `filePath` string array. In the beginning you need

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
```

also you need to add reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic`

Answer (score 1):

I did a simple way for seach as many extensions as you need, and with no ToLower(), RegEx, foreach...

```
List<String> myExtensions = new List<String>() { ".aspx", ".ascx", ".cs" }; // You can add as many extensions as you want.
DirectoryInfo myFolder = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\FolderFoo");
SearchOption option = SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly; // Use SearchOption.AllDirectories for seach in all subfolders.
List<FileInfo> myFiles = myFolder.EnumerateFiles("*.*", option)
    .Where(file => myExtensions
    .Any(e => String.Compare(file.Extension, e, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) == 0))
    .ToList();
```

Working on .Net Standard 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
var filtered = Directory.GetFiles(path)
    .Where(file => file.EndsWith("aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || file.EndsWith("ascx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Add additional explanation for the code. It might help OP understand your answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Just would like to say that if you use `FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles` instead of `Directory.GetFiles`, it will allow an array of wildcards.

For example:

```
Dim wildcards As String() = {"*.html", "*.zip"}
Dim ListFiles As List(Of String) = FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(directoryyouneed, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, wildcards).ToList
```

Comment: Where does one acquire `FileIO` ?

Comment: It should be already included in your environment in Visual Studio (2015). It is part of Microsoft.VisualBasic namespace. In my case is VisualBasic because that's my language of choice.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry to write this as an answer, but I don't have privileges to write comments yet.)

Note that the [FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.filesystem.getfiles#Microsoft_VisualBasic_FileIO_FileSystem_GetFiles_System_String_Microsoft_VisualBasic_FileIO_SearchOption_System_String___) method from Microsoft.VisualBasic is just a wrapper to execute a search for each provided pattern and merge the results.
When checking the source from the .pbd file, you can see from this fragment FileSystem.FindPaths is executed for each pattern in the collection:

```
private static void FindFilesOrDirectories(
  FileSystem.FileOrDirectory FileOrDirectory,
  string directory,
  SearchOption searchType,
  string[] wildcards,
  Collection<string> Results)
{
    // (...)
    string[] strArray = wildcards;
    int index = 0;
    while (index < strArray.Length)
    {
      string wildCard = strArray[index];
      FileSystem.AddToStringCollection(Results, FileSystem.FindPaths(FileOrDirectory, directory, wildCard));
      checked { ++index; }
    }
    // (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1035425/jonathan)'s answer (for 2 file extensions):

```
public static string[] GetFilesList(string dir) =>
    Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    .Union(Directory.GetFiles(dir, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories)).ToArray();
```

Or for more file extensions (search in this folder and subfolders):

```
public static List<string> GetFilesList(string dir, params string[] fileExtensions) {
    List<string> files = new List<string>();
    foreach (string fileExtension in fileExtensions) {
        files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(dir, fileExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    }
    return files;
}

List<string> files = GetFilesList("C:\\", "*.exe", "*.dll");
```

**In 3250 files took to find 1890 files takes 0.6 second.**