# Search a directory for all files of several types in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, .net-2.0

Say I have a string like "*.vcproj;*.csproj;*.sln" and I want to show all files of these types in a directory... Windows does this all the time with open-file dialogs.

I am aware of `Directory.GetFiles` but it only lets me run a given search pattern so I'd have to split my input and then loop over each.

Is there no built-in functionality to do this, after all the open-file dialog does it?

.NET 2 so no LINQ cleverness is usable!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you call Directory.GetFiles() with multiple filters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163162/can-you-call-directory-getfiles-with-multiple-filters)

Comment: Have a look at the answer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039580/multiple-file-extensions-searchpattern-for-system-io-directory-getfiles

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way:

```
string[] formats = {".jpg", ".png", ".txt"};
var files = Directory.GetFiles("C:\\");
var neededFiles = files.
    Where(file => formats.Any(file.EndsWith)).
    ToArray();
```

Alternatively, for .NET 2.0:

```
var desiredFiles = new List<string>(files.Length);
foreach (var file in files)
{
    foreach (var format in formats)
        if (file.EndsWith(format))
        {
            desiredFiles.Add(file);
            break;
        }
}
```

Comment: This uses linq, which he cannot use

Comment: @TimothyP Oops. I'll fix it.

Comment: I figured you'd be able to, that's why I didn't post my own reply, this one is yours :)

Comment: @TimothyP I could've bet that the author originally asked for all files with a certain filename and a format among the given ones, but your first edit is legit. About the `break`, it was to avoid useless checks. Without it, even after a file is recognized as .jpg (for instance), the comparison will be executed for all the other formats. I'm putting the `break` back.

Comment: Ah yes... like that, ok sorry, now I realize the break is perfectly valid

Answer (score 0):

You can use the vertical pipe '|' for [RegEx Alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). I think your final code should look something like:

```
string input_files = ".vcproj;.csproj;*.sln";
string search_for = input_files.Replace(".","\.").Replace(";","|")

Directory.GetFiles("/path/to/directory",search_for)
```

I've never done any coding in .NET so I apologize if my syntax is off. Obviously you can save some time if your initial string of search terms starts off in valid regex form.

Comment: What part of that syntax does GetFiles not support?

I'm going by: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz42302f.aspx

Comment: Only supports a single filter, for example "*.jpg" but not "*.jpg|*.png". Also it's Replace instead of replace and you need to prefix the \ with another \ otherwise it's an escape character

Comment: I used \ to escape the . because in matching expressions . generally represents a wildcard for any single character that isn't a newline [^\n]. Looking more closely at the documentation I can see that the only matching characters allowed are ? and * therefore the pipe won't work and the escaped . isn't needed.

Comment: @TimothyP - Your solution is better, but he could pass the string[] from Directory.GetFiles("/path/to/directory") through the RegEx method Matches, right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7sf90t3.aspx

Comment: yes, you are correct, in fact that is also part of his question +1