# Concatenating Arrays

Tags: arrays, unity-game-engine, concatenation

I'm getting the error: error CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to`string[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) Where do I cast?

```
IEnumerator LoadAllImages()
{
    string[] ARCTOPITHECUSPaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.png");      // get every file in chosen directory with the extension.png
    string[] GULONPaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/GULON/", "*.png");                      

    galleryArray = ARCTOPITHECUSPaths.Concat(GULONPaths);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) returns IEnumerable.
To convert it to array do following:

```
galleryArray = ARCTOPITHECUSPaths.Concat(GULONPaths).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I concat more than one additional array? I tried string[] galleryPaths = filePaths.Concat(gulonPaths, scythianWolfPaths).ToArray(); but that didn't work.

Comment: Just chain calls like this: array0.Concat(array1).Concat(array2).Concat(array3).ToArray()

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for the help!

Comment: Last question, when I get files with this line: 
  arctopithecusPaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.jpg"); is there a way to get files with multiple file extensions? I want to get both jpg and png but didn't know how to do that in a single line. Or do I just need to add another line? 
  arctopithecusPaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"/Users/kenmarold/Screenshots/ARCTOPITHECUS/", "*.png");

Comment: Some solutions to this are in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039580/multiple-file-extensions-searchpattern-for-system-io-directory-getfiles