# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process error while moving image

Tags: c#

I've a folder named `testPhotos` with some images. Based on the image creation date, I want to create a new folder by image creation year and then move the image to that folder.

For example, `testPhotos` has image named `01.jpg` which was created on 2011. So I want to create a folder named `2011` inside `testPhotos` like `testPhotos\2011` and move image to that folder. While doing this I am getting `The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. error while moving image from one folder to another.`

Code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var creationDate = new DateTime();
    var dateList = new List<String>();
    var fileName = String.Empty;
    var sourceFolder = @"C:\My Stuff\Test Porjects\testPhotos";

    String[] images = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);

    if (images.Count() > 0)
    {
        foreach (var imagePath in images)
        {
            fileName = Path.GetFileName(imagePath);
            creationDate = GetDateTakenFromImage(imagePath);
            var date = creationDate.GetDateTimeFormats()[5].Replace("-", "/");

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
            {
                var year = date.Substring(0, 4);
                var destinationFolder = sourceFolder + "\\" + year;

                if (!Directory.Exists(destinationFolder))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolder);

                    String fileToMove = sourceFolder+ "\\" + fileName;
                    String moveTo = destinationFolder + "\\" + fileName;

                    File.Move(fileToMove, moveTo);

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private DateTime GetDateTakenFromImage(string path)
{
    Image myImage = Image.FromFile(path);
    PropertyItem propItem = myImage.GetPropertyItem(36867);
    string dateTaken = new Regex(":").Replace(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(propItem.Value), "-", 2);
    return DateTime.Parse(dateTaken);
}
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

Any ideas?

Comment: I would guess you that you have a preview of that image or something else open, that already accesses the file.

Comment: Are you using `Image.FromFile()`?...

Comment: Bit of code review:  using the `Path.Combine` method is safer (more refactor-friendly; less error prone) than string concatenation when building file paths:   `String filePath = Path.Combine(sourceFolder, fileName);`

Comment: @MichaelSander I also assumed that but I am sure the image is neither open nor accessed by anything else.

Comment: @RobinHood if you accessed this file before, e.g. with streams, make sure to call `Dispose()`. Otherwise the file might still be locked until the garbage collector hooks in. Maybe you can share also some other code accessing this file? This would help identifieing the problem.

Comment: @MichaelSander Please see my updated code. I've posted my full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a missing dispose on the image, try with the following:

```
private DateTime GetDateTakenFromImage(string path)
{
    using (Image myImage = Image.FromFile(path))
    {
        PropertyItem propItem = myImage.GetPropertyItem(36867);
        string dateTaken = new Regex(":").Replace(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(propItem.Value), "-", 2);
        return DateTime.Parse(dateTaken);
    }
}
```

Comment: It works now. I am surprised I missed that but lesson learnt. Thank you

Comment: Quick question: How can I get only images from the folder? I tired `String[] images = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, "*.png" + "*.jpg" + "*.jpeg" + "*.jfif" + "*.bmp" + "*.tif" + "*.tiff" +  "*.gif");`  and `String[] images = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, "*.png; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.jfif; *.bmp;*.tif; *.tiff; *.gif");` but it returns nothing

Comment: [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7039580/multiple-file-extensions-searchpattern-for-system-io-directory-getfiles)