# Directory.GetFiles exclude certain file names via SearchPattern only

Tags: c#

Say I have "a.txt", "ab.txt", "c.txt" files inside C:\temp\someFolder.

I want to get all .txt files and filter "ab.txt" from results, but do it via SearchPattern only.

I would like to be able to do something like

```
Directory.GetFiles("C:\\temp", "*.txt -ab", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
```

as opposed to do the filtering outside the `GetFiles` function.

Is there a way?

Answer (score 6):

The `searchPattern` syntax is [very restricted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netcore-3.1#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_):

> The search string to match against the names of files in `path`. This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and wildcard (* and ?) characters, but it doesn't support regular expressions.

Wildcards allow to match multiple files with a given format, but don't allow exclusion, thus this is not possible.

You will have to rely either on filtering the result of `GetFiles`, or use `EnumerateFiles` with a filter expression, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7039644/8528014):

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles("c:\\temp", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
         .Where(f => Path.GetFileName(f) != "ab.txt")
         .ToArray();
```

Note that this approach calls the same internal function `InternalEnumeratePaths` in the `Directory` class (see [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/Directory.cs#L146) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/Directory.cs#L209)), thus it should not have any performance penalty; to the contrary, it should perform even better, due to calling `ToArray` *after* the collection has been filtered. This is especially true if a large amount of files match the initial `searchPattern`.

Answer (score 0):

I came to something similar today and, in my case, I needed the full FileInfo object.

I came to this

```
var path = @"C:\SomeDir\";
var dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var files = dInfo.GetFiles("*").Where(x => x.Name != "SomeFile.txt").ToArray();
```

I hope it's useful.